# Rails - Creating records with best in place gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, best-in-place

I have Items and Plans associated to those items

**item.rb**

```
name: string
cost: float
```

**plan.rb**

```
belongs_to: Item
percentage: float
month: integer
year: integer
```

I'm building a table where I want to edit and create plans. Something like this

```
Item     Jan 14    Feb 14    ...    Jan 15    Feb 15
 01        10%       12%              15%       20%       //Each column represents
 02         0%*      12%               0%*      20%       //a plan
 03        23%       12%              15%        0%*
```

I'm using [best in place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem to update those percentage and it works perfect. My problem is when a plan is not already created (the ones marked with *).
Is there a way to use best in place to fire an ajax call with POST method to create plans?

I could create plans for all the items before the table is displayed, but that's not my intention. Probably best in place it's not the best option and I should try another strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came across this pull request on the best in place gem:

Pull Request: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/pull/527

Branch: https://github.com/sbeam/best_in_place

It provides the ability to create new records with BIP and is working for my project. You can wait for it to be merged or install the branch by using this in the gemfile:

```
gem 'best_in_place', github: 'sbeam/best_in_place'
```

Unfortunately, there's no documentation on it yet, but the pull request files show how it can be used.

Comment: I've finally implemented it without best_in_place gem, but it is really good to know there's a solution to this problem :) Thanks!